# How do I condense this?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, exists

It's actually much longer than this.  What is the better way to do this?    I'm trying to write a decider that looks at files and determines which script to goto.

```
IF EXIST *x71c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x72c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x73c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x74c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x75c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x76c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x77c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x78c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x79c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x80c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x81c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x82c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x83c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x84c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x85c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x86c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x87c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x88c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *x89c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
IF EXIST *s20c48* (GOTO script-a) else goto script-b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your script is currently set, it will only execute the first line anyway.  If you meant:

```
IF EXIST *x71c48* (
    GOTO script-a
) else IF EXIST *x72c48* (
    GOTO script-a
) else IF EXIST *x73c48* (
    GOTO script-a
) else IF...
rem etc. etc. etc.
... else goto script-b
```

... then you could shorten it with a `findstr` regular expression and conditional execution.

```
dir /b | findstr /i "x[0-9][0-9]c[0-9][0-9]" >NUL && goto script-a || goto script-b
```

You could also use a `for /L` loop.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%I in (0,1,99) do (
    set "int=0%%I"
    if exist *x!int:~-2!c48* goto script-a
)
goto script-b
```