# Condensing If Statement Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, if-statement

I have this batch script that has numerous "if statements". Here are a couple lines of what I have:

```
if %c%==PC exit
if %c%==pc exit
if %c%==CMD exit
if %c%==cmd exit
if %c%==MENU exit
if %c%==menu exit
if %c%==KILL exit
if %c%==kill exit
```

There are many more possibilities and really could use some simplifying if it is possible. So is there a way I can simplify this? Perhaps something like, if the variable `c` is equal to any of these exit. Or even make the if statements case insenstitive Is this possible? Really, any way to simplify this would be awesome and could greatly reduce the size of my batch script.

*A couple side notes*

- This code already works and does not need to be edited with the exception of condensing it.
- I know there is a similar question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303906/how-do-i-condense-this), but I do not know how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?`.  I bet there is an option in there that will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the HELP for the `IF` command. **The /I switch, if specified, says to do case insensitive string compares.  The /I switch can also be used on the string1==string2 form of IF.**

```
if /I %c%==PC exit
if /I %c%==CMD exit
if /I %c%==MENU exit
if /I %c%==KILL exit
```

Comment: so if I use `/I` then I won't need to check for both `PC` and `pc`, right?

Comment: @BaliC, well in my world 4 is less than 8.

Comment: This works. I am using both your answer and the first answer. Both are helpful to me, for both helped me condense my script. I don't know who to choose as the best answer

Comment: @AChildofGod, if you use the /I switch in BaliC's code you just need one instance of each word to check. `for %%a in (pc cmd menu kill) do
if  /I %c%==%%a exit`

Answer (score 6):

This is the shortest method:

```
rem Next line is necessary to nest the value of one variable inside another one
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize the list of values enclosed by slash
set "values=/PC/CMD/MENU/KILL/"



if /I "!values:/%c%/=!" neq "%values%" exit
```

- The initialization of `values` variable just needs to made it once, at beginning
- The `!values:/%c%/=!` part first replaces the `%c%` variable; then try to remove such a value enclosed by slashes from `!values!` variable using Delayed Expansion.
- If the result is *different* than the original `%values%` variable, it means that `/%c%/` string appears *inside* `!values!`. In this case, execute `exit`.
- The `/I` switch in `if` command checks for both uppercase and lowercase (and any other letters combination) in `%c%`.

This method also allows to insert an `else` part in the `if` command in the simplest way, because there is *just one `if`*.

**EDIT**: As user LotPings indicated, it is not necessary to include the `/I` switch in this case because in the `%var:old=new%` replacement, the `old` string replacement from `%var%` value is case insensitive.

Comment: The `/i` switch isn't necessary here. The string replacement is case insensitive and the remaining part of value will have the same casing as the complete value. +1 for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array:

```
set arr=PC pc CMD cmd MENU menu KILL kill
for %%a in (%arr%) do (
if %c%==%%a exit
)
```

For multiple values, replace the `if` line with:

```
if %c%=="PC" if %c%=="pc"
```

It will only run the next line if all `if`'s are true.

Comment: One other thing. Is it possible to use two optional values that result in the same thing in one if statement?

Comment: Basically condensing this: 

`if %c%==PC start PC.bat`

`if %c%==pc start PC.bat`

Comment: Are either one of you going to read the help file for the `IF` command?

Comment: @AChildofGod You could chain the `if`'s together in one line, that would be the equivelant of an `or`

Comment: @Squashman Why don't you post an answer then if it's all in the help file?

Comment: @BaliC how would you chain them together? and what do you mean by "chain"?

Comment: @Squashman I'm trying to read the help file, it is somewhat confusing. So much information, and I am just sifting through it to find what I need

Comment: @AChildofGod See my updated answer, if you are just running files though it shouldn't be a problem as the files will be case insenstive.

Comment: @BaliC that last bit didn't work for me. Thanks for the array idea.

Comment: Just a suggestion: `for %%a in (pc cmd menu kill) do if /I %c%==%%a exit` . One line of code.

Comment: @AChildofGod, it is not an array.  It is just a string. There is no array type variable in batch-files.  It can be simulated though.

Comment: @Squashman Good idea, as long as you aren't adding more words that one liner works nicely and is still readable

Comment: @Squashman and BaliC thanks for the quick responses. I was sort of expecting answers later today.

Comment: @AChildofGod No probs :)

Comment: The chain of two `if`'s together is equivalent to an `AND`, _not_ to an `OR`; for example, there is no way that `if %c%==PC if %c%==pc exit` works. This is not an array because there are not subscripts involved.