# why does my program that changes color not work? Batch

Tags: batch-file

i was trying to make a programme that changed colour but it just does not work.
I press any button and it does not change and then just closes. I have no clue why it doesent work

```
@echo off
set letter2=0
:1
set color=%random%
if %color% LSS 10 goto next
goto 1
:next
set letter=%random%
if %random% LSS 6 goto 2
:2 
if %letter% == 0 goto A
if %letter% == 1 goto B
if %letter% == 2 goto C
if %letter% == 3 goto D
if %letter% == 4 goto E
if %letter% == 5 goto F
goto next
:a
set %letterr2% == a
goto final
:b
set %letterr2% == b
goto final
:c
set %letterr2% == c
goto final
:d
set %letterr2% == d
goto final
:e
set %letterr2% == e
goto final
:f
set %letterr2% == f
:final
set realcolor=%letter2%+%color%
cls
color %realcolor%
echo hey this color is %color%
pause>nul
goto 1
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple things going on here.

The biggest problem is that your `set` statements in `:a` through `:f` are completely wrong.

- When you write a set statement, only use one `=` symbol.
- When you say `set %letter2%=c`, you are not setting the value of letter2 to c, you are saying "set the value of **what the value of letter2 is** to c."
- Remove the spaces from both sides of the `=` symbol; batch allows spaces to be part of variable names, so you've created a variable called `%letterr2 %` and set its value to `c`.
- You made a typo and called the variable %letter**r**2% instead of %letter2%.

You don't need a `+` for string concatenation, just stick the two variables next to each other.

Your script is taking forever to run because %random% returns a number between 1 and 32768. The odds of it being under 10 are miniscule. The odds of it being under 6 are even smaller. When you want a random number between 1 and n, use the code `set /a number=%random% %% n`.

Ultimately, your code is going to look something like this:

```
@echo off
set letter2=0
:1
set /a color=%random%%%10
set /a letter=%random%%%6

if %letter% == 0 goto A
if %letter% == 1 goto B
if %letter% == 2 goto C
if %letter% == 3 goto D
if %letter% == 4 goto E
if %letter% == 5 goto F

:a
set letter2=a
goto final
:b
set letter2=b
goto final
:c
set letter2=c
goto final
:d
set letter2=d
goto final
:e
set letter2=e
goto final
:f
set letter2=f
:final
set realcolor=%letter2%%color%
cls
color %realcolor%
echo hey this color is %color%
pause>nul
goto 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know why your code does not work, see the [extensive explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345203/778560) of @SomethingDark.

However, if you want to see a simpler way to do the same thing, then you may review this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set letters=abcdef

:loop
set /A color=%random% %% 10
set /A letter=%random% %% 6

set letter2=!letters:~%letter%,1!

set realcolor=%letter2%%color%
cls
color %realcolor%
echo hey this color is %realcolor%
pause>nul
goto loop
```

They keypoint in this code is the use of Delayed Expansion, so I suggest you to search for such a term in this site where are tons of related answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324354/windows-batch-files-what-is-variable-expansion-and-what-does-enabledelayedexpa/25328044#25328044), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532216/cmd-piping-echo-to-set-expanding-variables-in-variables/35538235#35538235), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736051/condensing-if-statement-batch-file/42736759#42736759), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), or...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

:loop
    call :getRandom
    cls
    color %randomColor%
    echo This color is %randomColor%
    pause >nul
goto :loop

:getRandom
    set "randomColor="
    :getRandomLoop
        set /a "color=%random% %% 15"
        set "if=if %color%=="
        set "then=set color="
            %if%10 %then%A
            %if%11 %then%B
            %if%12 %then%C
            %if%13 %then%D
            %if%14 %then%E
            %if%15 %then%F
        set "randomColor=%randomColor%%color%"
        if "%randomColor:~1,1%"=="" goto :getRandomLoop
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Instead of giving new code, you should actually answer the question and explain why the existing code doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see the point in showing this type of code. It uses a syntax that nobody uses and that certainly will confuse a Batch file beginner, like the OP... **`:(`**

Comment: You should explain the reason for your downvote in my answer (other than a _revenge downvote_), like I did it here... **`:/`**